# How to use a loop to send messages 10 seconds apart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iteration, settimeout

In my code, the message sends every few seconds. How do I make it advance through messages instead of sending the same message over and over?

The first message is sent successfully, the second message needs to be sent with a few seconds delay from the first one.

```js
const tmi = require('tmi.js');

var value = true;

const options = {
  options: {
    debug: true,
  },
  connection: {
    cluster: 'aws',
    reconnect: true,
  },
  identity: {
    username: 'yessirski69', //username of the bot
    password: 'yolopoo', //login token of the bot
  },
  channels: ['mrpooski'], // the channel you are targetting
};

const client = new tmi.client(options);

client.connect();

var i = 1; //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop() { //  create a loop function
  setTimeout(function() { //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
    client.action('mrpooski', 'Hello This is the first message'); //  your code here
    i++; //  increment the counter
    if (i < 1000) { //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
      myLoop(); //  ..  again which will trigger another
    } //  ..  setTimeout()
  }, 3000)

}

myLoop(); //  start the loop
```

Comment: Simple settimeout should work

Comment: Hey @Bharat , would you know exactly how to write that into the code?

Comment: Are the messages stored in an array?

Comment: @denzaa Welcome to SO! What's wrong with the current code, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen Hey, basically I have it sending a message every 3 seconds successfully, but I haven't figured out how to add another message with the same 3 second delay from the first message being sent

Comment: Where is the second message? How are messages stored? For example, you could advance through an array of messages each time the loop runs.

Comment: @showdev The second message isn't implemented into the code yet, I have no clue how to add it with a sleep because whenever I add it, it doesnt sleep for 3 seconds from the first one being sent. ATM only the first message is there.

Comment: I have posted a simple sample, where messages are in array and they are logged every 3 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel, [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) should be used for executing a function repeatedly after a defined period instead of [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```js
let messages = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4", "Message 5", "Message 6"];
let counter = 0;
let timer;

function myLoop() {
  var date = new Date();
  if (!messages[counter]) return clearInterval(timer);
  console.log(date + " : " + messages[counter]);
  counter++;
}


timer = setInterval(myLoop, 3000);
```

Comment: @denzaa please accept the answer so that it may helps others in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple loop that runs every 3 seconds. You can extend this code to read your message from array or some other function (may be use yield)

```js
var messages = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3","Message 4","Message 5","Message 6"];
var counter = 0;

function myLoop() {  
var date = new Date();
console.log(date + " : " + messages[counter++]);

setTimeout(myLoop, 3000);

}


myLoop();
```

Comment: If this is what you are looking for, please accept answer, else let me know what is that you are looking for?

Comment: From where would get you messages? once you decide on that part all you have to do is replace this code with client.action('mrpooski',<your message>); read aout `yield`, i see this also would be gr8 here

Answer (score 0):

Bharat provided the correct answer :)

```
var messages = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3","Message 4","Message 5","Message 6"];
var counter = 0;

function myLoop() {  
var date = new Date();
console.log(date + " : " + messages[counter++]);

setTimeout(myLoop, 3000);

}


myLoop();
```